# How to access a value type in a collection by reference?

Tags: c#, collections, value-type

Is there anyway to obtain a value type by reference as opposed to by value from a collection of value types, similar to the way one can pass a value type by reference to a method?

```
var myInts = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var item1 = myInts[0];
item1 += 23;
Console.WriteLine(myInts[0]);
// ouputs: 1
myInts[0] += 987;
Console.WriteLine(myInts[0]);
// outputs: 988
```

So the modification to the `item1` variable would be modifying the element in the collection too.

Using the indexer works as above because I am re-assigning the element after getting it.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek OK, I changed my title back though cause you changed the question - I don't want to access an object i.e. box the value.

Comment: I know you don't, but that is how it's called. You don't access a value type, you access an object of a value type. The object in this context does not mean a reference typed object, but rather an entry of a collection or a working item. "A value type" should not be understood as some variable, but like a general type (int, double, etc.) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

When you write

```
var item1 = myInts[0];
```

The value that is stored in the position with index 0 in the list called `myInts` is assigned to the item1 variable. Since this list is a list of value types, the value that is assigned to the `item1` is the actual value of the element in zero position, it isn't a reference like it wold be if `myInts` were holding the instances of a reference type. So any modification to the value that is assigned to `item1` will not result to a modification to the element `myInts[0]`.

Actually, I don't see a reason why something like that you are asking would be useful. If you could point us a use case where this would be beneficial, I would be grateful to you.

Comment: A little inconsistent that `myInts[0] += 987` works, not that I am complaining. I got caught out in a `for` loop modifying a variable thinking it would be updated in collection - but that was just my bad - it does mean however I now have to use the indexer everytime I modify it in my `for` loop or re-assign the element at the same position.

Comment: Actually I realize now `myInts[0] += 987` works becuase I am re-assigning the element at that position.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

If you're asking about `Int32`, answer is *no*. If it is your own struct you can achieve it by "interfaces".

```
interface IMyInt
{
    int Value{get;set;}
}

struct MyInt : IMyInt
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var myInts = new List<IMyInt> { new MyInt{ Value = 1}, new MyInt{ Value = 2}, new MyInt{ Value = 3} };
    var item1 = myInts[0];
    item1.Value += 23;
    Console.WriteLine(myInts[0].Value);
}
```

Prints

```
24
```

This works because `myInts` contains list of boxed structs which will be copied by reference.

Comment: Yup I realize I can box the the values - I would probably just use a class rather than a struct with an interface.

Comment: @markmnl Yup, honestly class is better choice. but this technique can help if you're struck with structs.

Answer (score 0):

You can play a little trickery with lambdas to get something that may work the way you want.

So if you are happy to pass around a reference to a `Action<Func<int, int>>` you can update the elements of a collection.

So given:

```
var myInts = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I can define a delegate like this:

```
Action<Func<int, int>> updateItem1 = f => myInts[0] = f(myInts[0]);
```

Now I can pass around `Action<Func<int, int>> updateItem1` anywhere and use it like this:

```
updateItem1(x => x + 23);
updateItem1(x => x + 987);
```

And this updates the elements of the collection without passing around the collection.

Try it like this:

```
var myInts = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

Action<Func<int, int>> updateItem1 =
    f => myInts[0] = f(myInts[0]);

updateItem1(x => x + 23);
Console.WriteLine(myInts[0]); // 24
updateItem1(x => x + 987);
Console.WriteLine(myInts[0]); // 1011
```

Answer (score 0):

In an array, field, or an assignable variable, you can do it, with `ref` keyword.

```
var myInts = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
ref var item1 = ref myInts[0];
item1 += 23;
Console.WriteLine(myInts[0]);   // outputs: 24
myInts[0] += 987;
Console.WriteLine(myInts[0]);   // outputs: 1011
Console.WriteLine(item1);       // outputs: 1011
```

In a collection, you cannot. (At least, in a List you cannot; I just assume other collections are implemented the same). For root cause, you can see here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,181

You can see the indexer returns `return _items[index];` which means the return value of the `List` indexer is a temporary copy of the element.

```
// This does not compile. The error is "A property or indexer may not 
//     be passed as an out or ref parameter" or "Indexer access returns
//     temporary value. 'ref' argument must be an assignable variable,
//     field, or an array element."
var myInts2 = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
ref var item2 = ref myInts2[0];
```